Checker Framework fails on all Windows machines in my team
I tried to integrate the Checker Framework in out project. Unfortunately crashes on all Windows machines in my team. The actual error message I was only able to retrieve by extracting the compiler options from the output of the Maven Compiler Plugin and to run javac by my own on the commandline.
This showed the Checker Framework fails with this error message:
End of remainingJdkStubFilesJar for KeyForAnnotatedTypeFactory from
[file:/c:/opt/mavencache/org/checkerframework/checker/3.47.0/checker-3.47.0.jar](file:///c:/opt/mavencache/org/checkerframework/checker/3.47.0/checker-3.47.0.jar).
Contents of
[file:/c:/opt/mavencache/org/checkerframework/checker/3.47.0/checker-3.47.0.jar](file:///c:/opt/mavencache/org/checkerframework/checker/3.47.0/checker-3.47.0.jar):
error: Error when invoking constructor
org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.KeyForAnnotatedTypeFactory(class
org.checkerframework.common.basetype.BaseTypeChecker) on args
[org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.KeyForSubchecker@cb2d73]; cause:
Cannot open the jar file
[file:/c:/opt/mavencache/org/checkerframework/checker/3.47.0/checker-3.47.0.jar](file:///c:/opt/mavencache/org/checkerframework/checker/3.47.0/checker-3.47.0.jar)
  ; The Checker Framework crashed.  Please report the crash. Version:
Checker Framework 3.47.0.

  Exception: org.checkerframework.javacutil.BugInCF: Cannot open the
jar file
[file:/c:/opt/mavencache/org/checkerframework/checker/3.47.0/checker-3.47.0.jar](file:///c:/opt/mavencache/org/checkerframework/checker/3.47.0/checker-3.47.0.jar);
org.checkerframework.javacutil.BugInCF: Cannot open the jar file
[file:/c:/opt/mavencache/org/checkerframework/checker/3.47.0/checker-3.47.0.jar](file:///c:/opt/mavencache/org/checkerframework/checker/3.47.0/checker-3.47.0.jar)

This problem exists only on Windows. On Linux and Mac everything is fine.
Does someone know this problem?

Does the jar file exists at file:/c:/opt/mavencache/org/checkerframework/checker/3.47.0/checker-3.47.0.jar?
